# Calling a Java method with unknown type and passing the result in another Java method from Scala doesn't compile

Tags: scala, generics, optaplanner

I'm playing with Optaplanner in Scala and I'm calling the "groupBy" method like this:

```
    factory
      .forEach(classOf[ClassA])
      .filter(classA => classA.classB != null)
      .groupBy((classA: ClassA) => classA.classB)
      ....
```

This works. However, if I try to add the [count() constraint collector](https://www.optaplanner.org/docs/optaplanner/latest/constraint-streams/constraint-streams.html#collectorsCount) like this:

```
    factory
      .forEach(classOf[ClassA])
      .filter(classA => classA.classB != null)
      .groupBy((classA: ClassA) => classA.classB, count())
      ....
```

it complains with "Cannot resolve overloaded method 'groupBy'".

I have tried passing explicitly the generic type:

```
    factory
      .forEach(classOf[ClassA])
      .filter(classA => classA.classB != null)
      .groupBy((classA: ClassA) => classA.classB, count[ClassB]())
      ....
```

The count() constraint collector parameter has type
`UniConstraintCollector[ClassB, _, Integer]`

Whereas the groupBy method has signature:

```
<GroupKey_, ResultContainer_, Result_> BiConstraintStream<GroupKey_, Result_> groupBy(
            Function<A, GroupKey_> groupKeyMapping,
            UniConstraintCollector<A, ResultContainer_, Result_> collector)
```

But it doesn't change the outcome.

Any idea what's wrong here?

Comment: The signature of the `groupBy` you want to implement is actually `<GroupKey_, ResultContainer_, Result_>
BiConstraintStream<GroupKey_,Result_> groupBy(BiFunction<A,B,GroupKey_> groupKeyMapping,
 BiConstraintCollector<A,B,ResultContainer_,Result_> collector)` I believe. Have you tried specify the complete types?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I think the actual signature is 
'<GroupKey_, ResultContainer_, Result_> BiConstraintStream<GroupKey_, Result_> groupBy(
            Function<A, GroupKey_> groupKeyMapping,
            UniConstraintCollector<A, ResultContainer_, Result_> collector)'

However, I shouldn't have to implement it as there is already an available implementation in Optaplanner.

I have updated the above question with the correct signature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the signature, both function arguments of `groupBy` should map from the same `A` but you're trying to apply it to the 1st function mapping from `ClassA` and the 2nd function mapping from `ClassB`.

The following compiles:

```
.groupBy((classA: ClassA) => classA.classB, count[ClassA]())
```

Do you want the following?

```
.groupBy((classA: ClassA) => classA.classB)
.groupBy(count[ClassB]())
```